# Swift generics postponed issue

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, generic-programming

I'm trying to do this but I'm getting some troubles

This is CustomProtocol

```
protocol CustomProtocol {

}
```

SubCustomProtocol

```
protocol SubCustomProtocol: CustomProtocol {

}
```

SubCustomProtocolImplementation

```
class SubCustomProtocolImplementation: SubCustomProtocol {

}
```

This is CustomClass

```
class CustomClass<P: CustomProtocol> {

    var customProtocol: P?

    func doSomething() {

    } 

}
```

SubCustomClass

```
class SubCustomClass<P: SubCustomProtocol>: CustomSubClass {

}
```

And my BaseViewController

```
class BaseViewController<P: CustomProtocol, T: CustomClass<P>>: UIViewController {

    var foo: T!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        foo?.doSomething()
    }
}
```

My ViewController

```
class ViewController<P: SubCustomProtocolImplementation, T: SubCustomClass<P>>: BaseViewController<P,T> {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

In the line where I call foo?.doSomething() it says that 'T' is not a subtype of 'CustomClass<'P'>' and I don't know what I'm doing wrong

And in the ViewController declaration it says that "BaseViewController requires 
that T inherit from CustomClass<'P'>"

Hope you can help me!

Comment: I'm not getting this error. At least in playground. Are you sure you're providing the full context?

Comment: @Iyuna I was missing something sorry! I edited the question

Comment: It seems, a type parameter cannot be constrained by a generic class. It _can_ be constrained by a class or a protocol.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper so basically I can't postpone generics right?

Comment: It seems we cannot do this yet. Swift is still not a complete full-fledged language. I would recommend to file a feature request. At least you can work around it, as shown by @lyuna.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specify your foo var type as `CustomClass<P>` you should do as following instead.

```
class ViewController<P: CustomProtocol>: UIViewController {

    var foo: CustomClass<P>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        foo?.doSomething()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks I know, I wasn't explaining it very well, I've edited my question again